# How can I exit the loop when the zip file is extracted successfully in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, exception, zip

I've been working lately on a zip brute-forcer.

My problem is that when I run the code it overwrites the extracted file.
It doesn't stop when the file is successfully extracted.

So I want to exit the loop when the file successfully extracted, but I couldn't find a way around it.

Any ideas?

```
import sys
import zipfile
import os
L = ['password1','password2','password3','password4','password5']
zipfilename = 'file.zip'
#loop through the passwords list and try to extract the file
for x in L:
        try:
                zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)
                zip_file.extractall("extracting_directory",pwd=x)
#ignore errors "wrong password attempts stops the loop"
        except:
                pass

#list all files in the dir to make sur u extracted it successfully
x = os.listdir("extracting_diectory")
print x

#read the output file
fh = open('/extracting_directory/myfile.txt','r') 
print fh.read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add, for instance, an else-branch to your `try-except` and `break` the loop:

```
try:
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)
    zip_file.extractall("extracting_directory",pwd=x)
except Exception:
    pass
else:
    break
```

The `else`-block is executed if the `try`-block finished without any exception. You could also add the `break` to the end of your `try`-block here.

Comment: that was fast !

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully `extractall` you want to `break` out of the loop:

```
for x in L:
    try:
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)
        zip_file.extractall("extracting_directory",pwd=x)
        break
    except:
        pass
```